# C# : how to set stored procedure execution with parallelism or improve execution time?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I apologise if my question it too stupid or if it is a duplicate, but I didn't find any solution for my problem. Thanks for any advice or answers!

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 project, I get data from a SQL Server table with more than 1.5 million records.

To prevent SQL injection, I always use only parametrized queries and it generated stored procedure.

For example one of queries that I send to server:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 5 NAME
                                            FROM TABLE_NAME 
                                            WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE @Param", connection);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", "someValue");

    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;

    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
}
```

Result in SQL Server Profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP 5 NAME FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE @Param',N'@Param nvarchar(11)',@Param=N'%someValue%'
```

If there are just a few records in the table, which is suitable to search criteria, it must check all 1.5 millions orders before returning a result.

I noticed that if I select top 1000 records, SQL Server searches the `orders` table with paralelism and it works much faster, but it doesn't work with a stored  procedure.

So what I want to know is that could I send to server stored procedure with parallelism or could I send parametrized query not like stored procedure, but like just command?

Edit: I added the execution plan, hoping that it helps.

[image]

Comment: There are other ways to optimise this. Views can be used for example. They allow hte DBMS to do considerable caching. You should defeinitely put an index onto that row. The Idex structure is designed to be efficient for Text searches (http://sqlity.net/en/2445/b-plus-tree/). Asuming that your SQL server will have enough Cores to throw more threads at the problem is a bad idea. Not to mention that the real bottleneck will always be the disk and the network.

Comment: Is COLUMN_NAME indexed?

Comment: @Christopher we are already put indexes, but indexes don't work with % as we noticed. I mean that it give too small profit if parameter like %value%.

Comment: @MJH yes, it is.

Comment: Can you share the plan?

Comment: @IhorMykytiv: It could help a lot if you gave use the DDL commands to make those tables (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language). That way we would know this and might be able to spot some issues in teh shema.

Comment: Nitpicking - that's not a stored procedure, it's a parameterized query.

Comment: @MJH shared, hope it helps.

Comment: It is possible to enforce sequential execution (`OPTION (MAXDOP 1)`), but it is impossible to enforce parallel execution. Even your `TOP(1000)` produces parallelism by chance -- for other table sizes and parameters, it could easily be sequential again. These sorts of catch-all queries are better served with full-text indexing. You can force the query to be "maximally bad" by omitting the `TOP(5)` and then reading only the first 5 rows with a data reader, but this causes SQL Server to overcommit resources in a quite dramatic way. It's not a good strategy just to get parallelism.

Comment: checkout this article, it will help you to understand why an index scan is performed instead of an index seek.

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/identifying-and-solving-index-scan-problems/

According to the article, I suspect your search term is LIKE ('%value%') or ('%value') which will result in an index scan. This is the nature of your search term.

If it is possible to write it as LIKE ('value%'), this alone will provide significant performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following index:

```
create index idx_test on MyTable (Column_Name) include(Name)
```

And modify your query with an index hint:

```
SELECT TOP 5 NAME FROM TABLE_NAME with(index(idx_test)) WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE @Param
```

This caused the query to run twice as fast on my system.